# The usage about "Never ever"

Tags: grammar

It can always heard in movies.

> "I'll never ever see you again."

If I want to say that "I will not choose this forever", can I use *never ever*?
For example:

> I will never ever choose this.

Is that the right way to say?

Comment: All that you are doing, when you say *never ever* is to intensify the remark. It means exactly the same as 'I will never go'. Sometimes people say 'I will *never never* do such and such'. I suppose because *never* is not gradable it does not take the usual adverbial intensifiers like *very*, or *moderately* etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's completely fine, except some people (like me) would put a comma between 'never' and 'ever'.

You can also say, "I have *never, ever* [done something]." In fact, there's a drinking game called "Never Have I Ever..." It's a fun way to practice the present perfect tense/aspect. ^_^

Comment: No comma is needed there. It's a matter of style whether to use one.